# Selenium: wait_for_* and friends in Selenium RC ruby driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, selenium, integration-testing

Are there any implementations of all the nifty [Selenium on Rails](http://selenium-on-rails.openqa.org) methods like `wait_for_visible`, `assert_not_text_present`, ...  for the **ruby driver of Selenium RC**?

If not, how would I go about implementing something like wait_for_visible?

Comment: It appears as though the Selenium RC server is setup to handle all the commands  (i.e. for every method selenium server command getFoo, there is also assertFoo, verifyFoo waitForFoo waitForNotFoo, ...)  Not all of these commands have made it into the selenium.rb that comes with server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my own problem.

I found the official ruby client at the [Git Hub Repository](http://github.com/ph7/selenium-client/tree/master)

I wrote this solution so you can just `require` this code then you can use all the useful `wait_for_*, assert_*, assert_not_*, wait_for_not_*, verify_*, and verify_not_*` commands.

```
#need this for starts_with? and camelize
require 'activesupport'
module Selenium
  module Client
    class Driver
      def method_missing(method, *args)
        method_prefixes = %w(wait_for wait_for_not assert_ assert_not verify verify_not store)
        method_name = method.to_s

        prefix = method_prefixes.find {|pre| method_name.starts_with?(pre)}

        #if the method starts with a prefix, camelize the name.
        if(prefix)
          string_command method_name.camelize(:lower), *args
        else
          super *args
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```