# Rails3 Google Maps testing with selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to test a google maps app with Rails3. I'm using cucumber with capybara and selenium for JavaScript testing.
I have a map where I wait for google maps to be loaded, and then send an ajax request to my server, where I get locations that I'm inserting into the map.
I'm wondering if it's possible with selenium to wait until google maps is loaded, the ajax call to my server is finished and the marker are placed inside the map. The other issue is, how to select this marker within google maps. Are there any selectors?

Or should I go the other way, and use a JS testing framework like Jasmine to test if my classes are loaded and so on. I don't have any experience with Jasmine, so is it possible to test a google maps?

Maybe someone knows a solution, or a hint if it's not possible, or a workaround or... ;)

**[UPDATE 1]**

<strike>I've found out how to select markers in google maps. If you look at [googles selenium tests](http://gmaps-api-issues.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/selenium/core/TestRunner.html?test=../tests/examples_stable_suite.html) you can check out what they are doing. For example selecting a marker:</strike>

```
waitForElementPresent   xpath=//img[contains(@src,'marker')]
```

But here comes the next problem. How do I select a specific marker? Is there a way inside the javascript google maps API to assign an ID to it, so that I can use `#marker_1`, `#marker_2`...?

And another strange thing is, that function like `wait_for_element` or `wait_for_condition` aren't available inside my cucumber step definitions. Are the google selenium tests using own function like that `waitForElementPresent`? Or are this standard selenium functions? I've found a lots of posts, where they always use something like

```
selenium.wait_for_condition
selenium.wait_for_element

or

@selenium.wait_for_condition
...
```

Inside my step definitions the `selenium` and the `@selenium` var a nil. How can I access this methods? I've also found this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211181/selenium-wait-for-and-friends-in-selenium-rc-ruby-driver)**, but it is from Oct. '08, so I think there must be a better solution (btw. this solution works on the first sight).

Like on this **[page](http://snipplr.com/view/16557/waiting-for-events-with-the-seleniumclient-ruby-driver/)**, they give an overview of a few selenium methods how to wait for a condition or element. Is this still present? How can I use this functions?

**[UPDATE 2]**

Damn it, I've found out, that the selenium tests I mentioned above are for V2 of google maps, not for V3. I have tried it with

```
wait_until { page.has_xpath?("//img[contains(@src,'marker')]") }
```

But it doesn't work. The marker is visible on the map, but I get a timeout error, because with this XPath selector it is not found. I'm wondering if it is generally possible to select a marker out of the DOM.

I also tried to assign an additional attribute to the marker when I create it:

```
// marker is the marker returned by google maps after adding it to the map
$(marker).attr('id', "marker_1");
```

But when I try to access it with the jQuery selector `$("#marker_1")`, it doesn't find it. So, still no solution, yet.

Comment: great question, I'd like to include these in my gmaps4rails gem

Comment: I was under the impression that because Selenium is written in Javascript, the security measures of browser JS engines prevent testing between domains (as a method of cross-site scripting prevention.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do with mine is to execute the calls in your step definitions like so:

page.execute_script("launchmap()")

then check for their existence in the page..then do your normal ajax check in capybara. the marker will be contained in a div right? then if you call launchmap and create the markers, capybara SHOULD be able find your markers

**UPDATE**

found out about this plugin: http://vigetlabs.github.com/jmapping/examples/

it gives you semantic markup for your google maps(for graceful degradation) allowing you to actually check if a marker exists using capybara. hope it helps(dont have time to test it but it looks promising)

Comment: thx for your answer! Why should I call a launchmap() when I'm doing integration tests? Aren't they designed to test user behaviour? In my opinion they should test the sites "as they are" without calling extra javascript from inside the tests.
Could you give me an example how you would select the markers? Sorry but I don't get your point at "...capybara SHOULD be able find your markers". thx and best regards!

Comment: hmm i think i misremembered about markers having div ids in them. in any case, you're calling the script to know that it runs. if the script fails to run capybara will return false. so it's a check already. you COULD also try: page.evaluate_script("launchmap()") if your launchmap function returns true, but take note that it might break under complex functions as said here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Comment: the plugin looks good, but this is a lot of extra code, I have to inlcude. It uses the marker manager for GM and a meta tag plugin for jQuery. I'm wondering if its generally possible to select markers out of jQuery, or XPath or any other DOM selector. I tried also the selenium plugin for Firefox, where you can record your click actions etc.pp. But I don't get a good result, as long it only selects the overlaying divs IMHO. Any other idea?

Comment: well either use that(as it is certainly a good addition to your code...i myself will use it when a chance comes) or you'll have to make all your functions in jquery or google maps to return something so you can evaluate it using page.evaluate_script. something like page.evaluate("placemarker(xcoor,ycoor)" == (something function returns to check if the marker was placed)

Comment: hmmm, but what if I want to test, that my custom info window opens when I click on a marker? How could I simulate that? Trigger a click event on the JS object?

Comment: is your custome window a new window or a div?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to Integration test my Google map with RSpec and Capybara. I wanted to write a test to assert that the content I got from an internal JSON-feed ended up in form of markers and info windows on my map (Google Maps API V3) in a Rails 4 app.

The problem:
Even when I ran the tests with Selenium Webdriver that supports JS, I didn't find a way to select the markers with Capybara to check for their content.

My solution:
1. I added a div with ID test-box to my HTML markup
2. I wrote three helper methods into my JS that had access to my maps markers and added the results to the test-box.
3. In Capybara I executed the helper methods and expected to find the expected content or values in the box.

The code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="info-box"></div>
```

**JS-helpers:**
in app/assets/javascripts/events.js

```
// Test helper methods
testInfo = function(){
  document.getElementById("info-box").innerHTML = markers[0].title;
};

testInfoCount = function(){
  document.getElementById("info-box").innerHTML = markers.length;
};

testInfoWindow = function(){
  document.getElementById("info-box").innerHTML = markers[0].title + ", " + markers[0].time;
};
```

"markers" in my code is an array I push in every marker after I have added it to the map. I can be sure that the content actually is on the map if it's in the markers array.

**Test:**

```
spec/features/map_feature_spec.rb:

require "rails_helper"

describe "Map", js: true do
  let!(:john){create(:user)}
  let!(:event1){create(:event, user: john)}
  let!(:event2){create(:event)}

  it "shows a marker for a geocoded event on front page" do
    visit '/'
    find('#main-map-canvas')
    page.execute_script('testInfo()')
    expect(page.find("div#info-box").text).to eq(event1.title)
  end

  it "shows a marker for each geocoded event on front page" do
    visit '/'
    find('#main-map-canvas')
    page.execute_script('testInfoCount()')
    expect(page.find("div#info-box").text).to eq("2")
  end


  it "shows a marker for an event on event's page" do
    visit "/events/#{event1.id}"
    expect(page).to have_css("#single-map-canvas")
    page.execute_script('testInfo()')
    expect(page.find("div#info-box").text).to eq(event1.title)
  end

  context "Tooltips" do
  let!(:event1){create(:event)}
  let!(:event2){create(:event)}

    it "shows title and date on frontpage" do
      visit "/"
      find('#main-map-canvas')
      page.execute_script('testInfoWindow()')
      expect(page.find("div#info-box")).to have_content("Pauls Birthday Party, #{event1.nice_date}")
    end

  end
end
```

- To run the javascripts Selenium webdriver and Firefox need to be installed (''gem "selenium-webdriver"'' in your Gemfile)
- I'm creating the test content (let!...) using Factory Girl.
- Running the tests you will actually see the markers on the map and their content appears in the test-box.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question - use waitForCondition with a script that tests for the presense of the markers.

```
waitForCondition ( script,timeout ) Runs the specified JavaScript snippet repeatedly until it evaluates to "true". The snippet may have multiple lines, but only the result of the last line will be considered. Note that, by default, the snippet will be run in the runner's test window, not in the window of your application. To get the window of your application, you can use the JavaScript snippet selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow(), and then run your JavaScript in there

Arguments:

script - the JavaScript snippet to run timeout - a timeout in milliseconds, after which this command will return with an error
```

Comment: I've tried it out, and as you can see in my updated question, I can't use this `waitForCondition` or `wait_for_condition` function. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to enable the url capybara is using to run the test server into google console for your app.

You can check this URL (and the error message while loading google maps) by setting `config.debug= true` within Capybara driver config loading block.